# System.getenv("EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET") returns null on Moto X Play (Android 6)

Tags: android

I am trying to get the path of the emulated storage in my android app using this

```
System.getenv("EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET")
```

This works fine on all devices so far except for Moto X play (Android 6.0). It returns `null` in this case, even though emulated storage is present. The path should be `/storage/emulated/` but the `System.getenv("EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET")` returns `null`. I tried to find the solution but didn't find anything. Can someone please help me. Thanks !!

Comment: I have the same problem on Asus Zenfone2, Marshmallow 6.0.1. Any luck on the problem?

Comment: Hey, I found that this command gives different results depending upon the manufacturer. You will have to use a different approach to solve your problem instead of using the above command.

Comment: yes i use different approach to get the EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET, but i don't know if it is optimized. I will post my solution here

Comment: external storage changed in android 6, and along with it "easy" ways to obtain those paths; you should be using the `Context` class to obtain paths in a vendor-agnostic way, not with environment variables.  Also, path "should be" whatever the vendor sets it to!

Answer (score 0):

So here is my workaround to get EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET

```
List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
File[] files = context.getExternalFilesDirs(null);
for (File file : files) {
    String applicationSpecificAbsolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    String emulatedRootPath = applicationSpecificAbsolutePath.substring(0, applicationSpecificAbsolutePath.indexOf("Android/data"));
    paths.add(emulatedRootPath);
}
//do what you want with the result paths
```

If you have any question or suggestion, let me know